# file copy on save or upload in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I work frequently providing custom java script solutions to SharePoint. The annoying part at the moment is that either I need to setup a watcher to check file changes and overwrite it in the directory where the files will be in SharePoint or I just move then manually. Is there anyway we can setup something with a config file, like it is with the watch tsc compiler.

All I want is, for example to run robocopy when I save a file.

Or even just overwrite the same file specified location, preferable not dependent on extensions.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering. I was able to achieve it with the simplest way I can think of: by using fs.watch or node-watch package.

created a js file with the code below to watch file changes in the src dir and act depending on the event.

watch.js:

```
//if you are using fs: 
//var fs = require('fs');
//
var watch = require('node-watch');
//fs.watch if using the node fs.
watch('./src/',{recursive: true}, async function(evt, name) {
  if (evt == 'remove') {
    // on delete runs rest call to delete the file
  }

  if (evt == 'update') {
    // on create or modify runs rest to upload the file
  }
}
```

with that you can either run the cmd "node watch.js"

or create a task to run on folderopen.

./.vs_code/tasks.json

```
{
    "type": "npm",
    "script": "watch",
    "label": "wathever label you want",
    "isBackground": true,
    "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "node watch.js"
  }
```

For the task to run on folderopen you also need to allow it in the folder. you can search on the command pallete (ctrl+shift+p), "Tasks:Manage Automatic Tasks in Folder" to enable it.